# Ошибки variable not defined в ms access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Ошибки проявляются  на разных переменных, Option explicit стоит во всех модулях.
Изменяю имя переменной в объявлении, меняю в функции - работает, возвращаю старое имя - работает, но появляется ошибка на другой переменной.

[image: Пример ошибки]

В чем может быть дело ?

Comment: ошибка на второй подчеркнутой строке

Comment: есть функция, вызываемая из другой функции в том же модуле, сейчас пишет что она не определена. С чем связаны эти проблемы ?

Comment: Похоже на повреждение базы. Скопируйте все в новую базу

Comment: сжал базу и ошибка исчезла

Answer (score 0):

1. Сжать базу (ну, это ты уже сделал)
2. **Декомпилировать базу:** `>msaccess.exe your.mdb /decompile`
3. Снова сжать.
4. Сохранить на будущее в темном прохладном месте.
   .